# NGINX LDAP ERROR (Error while initializing LDAP connection: (0, 'Error') )

Tags: linux, nginx, ldap, devops, openldap

This is my configuration. I keep getting this error: " Error while initializing LDAP connection: (0, 'Error') "
Similar LDAP filter works perfectly with other model:
I tried lots of possibilities, but none of them seem to work. I would really appreciate a help here.
https://github.com/kvspb/nginx-auth-ldap

I use this guide : https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ldap-auth

```
  location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.20.69:8080/main/;
        auth_request /auth-proxy;
               }

        location = /auth-proxy {
          internal;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        #proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        #proxy_cache auth_cache;
        #proxy_cache_valid 200 10m;
        #proxy_set_header X-CookieName "nginxauth";
        #proxy_set_header Cookie nginxauth=$cookie_nginxauth;
        proxy_set_header X-Ldap-URL "ldaps://ldap.jumpcloud.com:636/ou=Users,o=companyid,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=posixAccount)";
        proxy_set_header X-Ldap-BaseDN "ou=Users,o=companyid,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com";
        proxy_set_header X-Ldap-BindDN "uid=user-bind,ou=Users,o=companyid,dc=jumpcloud,dc=com";
        proxy_set_header X-Ldap-BindPass "password";
        proxy_set_header X-Ldap-Realm    Restricted;
```

Comment: Your base dn contains a typo I think : 'o=password' should be 'o=companyid'. Also note that `X-CookieName` and `Cookie nginxauth` are required if you are not using  HTTP basic authentication.

Comment: # (Required) The following directives set the cookie name and pass
            # it, respectively. They are required for cookie-based
            # authentication. Comment them out if using HTTP basic
            # authentication.
  Anyway I added them, but still doesn't work "password"was just a placeholder, it has the companyid. Thanks for the help though